# Unexpected "OPTIONS" method from Redirectresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC-Application I have my own error handling that catches different errors. If an authentication error occurs it redirects to a loginpage:

```
   public class JsonExceptionAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute   {
      if (filterContext.Exception.Message == "Auth expired")  {
         public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {         
            string newUrl = Logic.GetUrl());
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(newUrl, false);
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            return;         
         }
      }
   }
```

GetUrl() returns a valid Url.
This seems to work fine most of the time. It always returns a 302 redirect that will then call the new URL as a GET request.

But this does not work everywhere. If the Exception is thrown in my AuthorizeAttribute the 302 is still returned, but the Browser tries to open the Url with the httpmethod "OPTIONS" instead of GET causing an error:

[image: Browser Requests]

If I take the exact url and copy/paste it into the browser (so making a GET from it) it works fine. So where is this "OPTIONS" coming from all of a sudden?

*This happens in different browsers and the result is the same when I return the Redirect in the HandleUnauthorizedRequest in the AuthorizeAttribute instead of doing this in the HandleErrorAttribute*

Comment: Please read that, you will understand where it's coming from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS